# Is it possible to use Google Drive REST API to view another Google Drive account (not the users)

Tags: api, rest, google-drive-api, drive

I have a file on my Google Drive and I want to make an app that other people can use to be able to view it.

I want them to use my app to display the contents of my Google Drive File.
(I don't want to just email them a link that they paste into a Browser)

Can I use Google Drive Rest API to let them view my file, or 
does this API just allow them to view their own Google Drive files ?

If I can't use the Google Drive Rest API is there another way ?

Anybody have a clue ?

Comment: If your app does a server side connection, say using a service account you can retrieve anything you like from your account and send it to your client app. I do this. You can also share files with them or make the files public of course, and for some resources you can get, what I would call a hard to guess link. Really the right answer depends on your requirements.

Comment: So, do you have a server side for your app?